# SQLAlchemy: Operating on results

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do something relatively simple, spit out the column names and respective column values, and possibly filter out some columns so they aren't shown.

This is what I attempted ( after the initial connection of course ):

```
metadata = MetaData(engine)

users_table = Table('fusion_users', metadata, autoload=True)

s = users_table.select(users_table.c.user_name == username)
results = s.execute()

if results.rowcount != 1:
    return 'Sorry, user not found.'
else:
    for result in results:
    for x, y in result.items()
        print x, y
```

I looked at the API on SQLAlchemy ( v.5 ) but was rather confused. my 'result' in 'results' is a RowProxy, yet I don't think it's returning the right object for the .items() invocation.

Let's say my table structure is so:

```
user_id    user_name    user_password    user_country
0          john         a9fu93f39uf      usa
```

i want to filter and specify the column names to show ( i dont want to show the user_password obviously ) - how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `results` instantly as an iterator.

```
results = s.execute()

for row in results:
    print row
```

Selecting specific columns is done the following way:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import select

s = select([users_table.c.user_name, users_table.c.user_country], users_table.c.user_name == username)

for user_name, user_country in s.execute():
   print user_name, user_country
```

To print the column names additional to the values the way you have done it in your question should be the best because RowProxy is really nothing more than a ordered dictionary.

IMO the API documentation for SqlAlchemy is not really helpfull to learn how to use it. I would suggest you to read the [SQL Expression Language Tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html). It contains the most vital information about basic querying with SqlAlchemy.

Comment: The first snippet is what I initially came up with and returned everything.

For the second snippet I get "ValueError: too many values to unpack" - hrm?

Comment: Ah, I didn't specify the extra columns. Let's try it again.

Comment: TypeError: select() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)
>>  s = users_table.select(users_table.c.user_name, users_table.c.user_location,users_table.c.user_name == username)

Comment: Try again, I confused the syntax of select() with table.select().

Comment: Thanks - your modified version seems to work. But how could I also print the column name in addition to the value? So right now it spits out 'jeff', 'usa' whereas I actually want user_name: jeff, country: usa. 

It just feels a bit weird because the object returned is a "smart object" and not a regular simple dictionary/array that I can process the keys/values with...

Comment: No, the RowProxy is not that smart at all, it behaves like ordered dictionary with an additional tupel interface.

Comment: Note, pedantically, that at least in Python 2, `ResultProxy` is _not_ an _iterator_, you _will not be able to_ use `next()` on it! (It is, however, an iterable, which is why `for...in` works on it.) You have to apply `__iter__()` method on it to return a proper iterator (i.e. `next()` and `StopIteration` support)

Answer (score 16):

A SQLAlchemy [RowProxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html?highlight=rowproxy#sqlalchemy.engine.RowProxy) object has dict-like methods -- `.items()` to get all name/value pairs, `.keys()` to get just the names (e.g. to display them as a header line, then use `.values()` for the corresponding values or use each key to index into the `RowProxy` object, etc, etc -- so it being a "smart object" rather than a plain dict shouldn't inconvenience you unduly.